# Firebase Functions V1.0, access other projects database (Initializing change )

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Firebase as release the functions V1.0 and it means a lot of changes in the way to write the code.

I would like to do the migration, I understood all the changes, except the one about the admin.initializeApp
 Firebase says that

> firebase-admin is now initialized without any parameters within the
>   Cloud Functions runtime

But I need to access another project database from my actual project.

Until now I was doing it as follows :

```
/* Initialize the SecondApp service acccount */
var serviceAccount = require("./service-account.json");
/* Initialize SecondApp with the serviceAccount credentials */
var SecondApp = admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    apiKey: "**************",
    authDomain: "****************",
    databaseURL: "****************",
    projectId: "****************",
    storageBucket: "****************",
    messagingSenderId: "****************"},"SecondApp");
```

What will be the new way of doing it ?

Comment: The advice from the documentation is for the majority case where functions only access products from the same project.  Is there something that's not working the way you expect?

Comment: I still didn't migrate. For the moment I'm doing the change in my code to comply to the V1.
So you're saying that the V1 change nothing on the way to initialize another project database ?

Comment: Do you observe that anything behaves differently?  If not, and the documentation doesn't say you should change anything, just keep doing what you're doing

Comment: Just tested my code, and indeed no changes are needed on that part, it still work very well !
Thank very you very much to have taken the time to answer me.